# Function pointers, design

Tags: c

I am in a problem with a design question in C.

Let's say that I have a pretty large amount of functions, with different argument count.

POQ:

```
int print_one(int x)
{
    printf("one: %d\n", x);
    return 1;
}

int print_three(int x, int y, int z)
{
    printf("three: %d-%d-%d\n", x, y, z);
    return 3;
}
```

Now, I want to connect some properties to these functions in a structure, so that I can manipulate them without knowing the exact function, including their parameter count (I might even call the structure interface)

I tryd it like this, (& I think is pretty wrong):

```
typedef int (*pfunc)(int c, ...);

typedef struct _stroffunc
{
    pfunc myfunction;
    int flags;
    int some_thing_count;
    int arguments[10];
    int argumentcount;
} stroffunc;

int main()
{
    stroffunc firststruct;

    firststruct.pfunc = (pfunc) print_two;
    firststruct.something_count = 101;
    arguments[0] = 102;
    argumentcount = 1;
    flag &= SOME_SEXY_FLAG;

    // now I can call it, in a pretty ugly way ... however I want (with patially random results ofc)
    firststruct.pfunc(firststruct.arguments[0]);
    firststruct.pfunc(firststruct.arguments[0], 124, 11);
    firststruct.pfunc(1, firststruct.arguments[0], 124, 1, 1);
}
```

I find this solution very ugly, & I think (hope) that there is a better solution for calling & and setting the function pointers.

I'm just hoping, that I was clear enough ...
NOTE: I didn't compile this code, but i compiled & run a very similar one so the concepts are working.
NOTE: pure C needed

Comment: Casting to a variadic function pointer and then calling the function through it leads to undefined behaviour.  For a start, recall that the arguments to variadic functions undergo the *default argument promotions*, which is really going to screw things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a non-variadic function through a variadic function pointer leads to **undefined behaviour**.  For a start, recall that the arguments to variadic functions undergo the *default argument promotions* (`char`s are converted to `int`s, etc.), which will totally screw things up.

It's not clear how or why you intend to dynamically call a function with differing numbers of arguments.  But one solution could be to use a union:

```
typedef struct {
    int num_args;
    union {
        void (*f1)(int);
        void (*f2)(int, int);
        void (*f3)(int, int, int);
    } func;
} magic;


...

magic m;
...
switch (m.num_args) {
case 1: m.func.f1(arg1); break;
case 2: m.func.f2(arg1, arg2); break;
case 3: m.func.f3(arg1, arg2, arg3); break;
default: assert(0);
}
```

A second solution would be to rewrite all of your functions as variadic.

Comment: Rewriteing my function to variadic means that I write a ", ...)" at the end of every function of mine?

Comment: @lerosQ: Well, yes.  But it also means that any parameters that you intend to pass variadically (so all the parameters in your example) can no longer be explicitly declared (so e.g. `int print_three(int x, ...)`).

Answer (score 0):

This is on the edge of my knowledge, but I believe that you need to make the functions variadic as well, due to incompatibilities in the ABI.

see: [wikipedia's example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D)

Comment: I defined a type that is variadic, so i'm casting the functions to variadic.

Comment: right but the functions themselves aren't variadic functions, they use regular variables, which may not be stored in the same place, depending on ABI (stack vs register rx0-9 or something).

Comment: I guess I mis-understood that it was working or not, and if you don't know then I don't know what the issue is... you don't like the "smell"?

Comment: @lerosQ: that cast is invalid. You can't do that legally.

Comment: The example is working. My knowledge lacks a lot of things, but can you point that out with some document or logical reason? I was playing around with conventions as well (__stdcall & __cdecl), the stack is not getting corrupted at all.

Comment: i guess the big issue, is that if you used a variadic function, you would have to know how big all of the parameters were... which throws a wrench in the dynamism that would expect to gain.

Comment: if it is working that is great, but I don't think that it will necessarily be portable (i.e. may work in 32 bit linux but not 64 bit linux or may work for functions with 10 or fewer params, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a library which have some functions to handle the struct, like a "pseudo" class,

```
int initFunc(int (*pfunc)(int c,...));
```

This function will save the pointer into the struct, like a context in POO, in the struct you will use it like a "map" of all the function an you will call each one using an id.

which returns an id, and you save it in an array,
then another func say

```
int call(int id,int p1,...);
```

where you say the function id and the parameters, sure you must now which function is each id

Comment: This misses the unfortunate problem that calling non-variadic functions through a variadic function pointer is undefined behaviour, and almost certain to break something.